# While configuring svn in eclipse, svn:PROPFIND /DemoWeb// 405 method not allowed (http://localhost:8080)

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, eclipse-kepler

I found some question on the same error but I did not get the correct answer. That's why I am posting here my quest. My configurations are:

IDE:**Eclipse-kepler**

SVN Connector:**SVN Kit 1.3.5**

JDK: **JDK1.6**

While configuring below error is occurring.Thank you 
[image]

Comment: Is `http://localhost:8080/DemoWeb/` actually your subversion sever ? It sounds more like that's the URL to your webapp.

Comment: @nos Actually I don't know what I have to give in URL. So How can I set the subversion sever  URL. can you please tell me. Thank you

Comment: No I can't tell you. Noone here knows where your subversion server is. You have to find that out.